# Ngrx: Is it possible partially using async pipe?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am wondering if it's possible **partially** using async pipe while I use ngrx stroe.

For example,

```
// ts file
this.name$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(SOME.STATE),
      map((item) => {
        return item.name;
      })
    )

// html file
<p>{{name$ | async}}</p>
```

It's simple, but what if I need

```
// ts file
this.store.pipe(
      select(SOME.STATE),
    )
.subscribe(item => {
  this.name = item.name;
  this.age = item.age // <-
})

someMethod() {
  const age = this.age;
  // ...some processes using 'age' data which from store
}

// html file
<p>{{name}}</p>
```

Like above, if I have multiple data and I have to do some post-process( such as `someMethod()` ), I am not sure how to handle async pipe.
No more async pipe means also I have to `unsubscribe` manually which make more verbose code.

I have tried the below

```
// ts file
this.name$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(SOME.STATE),
      map((item) => {
        return item.name;
      })
    )

this.store.pipe(
      select(SOME.STATE),
    )
.subscribe(item => {
  this.age = item.age
})

someMethod() {
  const age = this.age;
  // ...some processes using 'age' data which from store
}


// html file
<p>{{name$ | async}}</p>
```

Working but I am wondering if there is better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to do some process on `age` for example and show it in the template?

Comment: In your examples you only use `name` in the template. Can you clarify?

Comment: `.subscribe(value => this.value = value)` is never a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tap` operator to do that instead of subscribing.

```
this.name$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(SOME.STATE),
    tap(item => this.age = item.age),
    map((item) => {
        return item.name;
    }));
```

There's still really no reason to do it this way though. Instead you should simply have another observable for example `age$`.